# function 'read.table' and error

Tags: r

This is my data as "*.txt"

```
ID    LBI   RTI  WDI FLA  PSF  FSF ZDF1 PROZD
ar      ?,35.30,2.60,  ?,42.4,24.2,47.1,69
arn  1.23,27.00,3.59,122, 0.0,40.0,40.0,30
be   1.24,26.50,2.90,121,16.0,20.7,29.7,72
bi1  1.07,29.10,3.10,114,44.0, 2.6,26.3,68
bi2  1.08,43.70,2.40,105,32.6, 5.8,10.7,42
bie  1.39,29.50,2.78,126,14.0, 0.0,50.0,78
bn   1.31,26.30,2.10,119,15.7,15.7,30.4,72
bo   1.27,27.60,3.50,116,16.8,23.0,35.2,69
by   1.11,32.60,2.90,113,15.8,15.8,15.0,57
```

Then, it failed when I command

```
r2 <- read.table('StoneFlakes.txt',header=TRUE,na.strings='?')
```

The error ;

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 9 elements
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: @germcd: it's not `','` for the first 2 columns though.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - and the header doesn't have `,` separators at all.

Comment: You may want to post the first few lines of `readLines("yourFile.txt")` It's not real clear where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
text <- readLines('StoneFlakes.txt')
text <- gsub(",", " ", text)
read.table(textConnection(text), header=TRUE, na.strings='?')
  #insted of using textConnection you can also use
read.table(text=text, header=TRUE, na.strings='?')
```